# Plumbing main line question high water bill

Tags: plumbing

I just got the bill from the water company and it was much higher then usual. It went from roughly $26 a month to $75. We had a small leak in the main line. This line was replaced and now my bill is three times normal. 
The only difference is the plumber changed the pipe from 1 inch to a 3/4" line. 
I have been checking the meter for hours and no movement. 
My question is can changing the size in the main line cause that large a increase? The woman at the water company says that if the meter is not working properly it would usually give a lower reading. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Changing the size of the main line would have no bearing (don't know *why* you would reduce the size though). Use a stethoscope to listen for flow in the main line with everything turned off, you must have a leak.

Comment: He said it didnt need 1" main line and to save money. But how can I have a leak if the meter hasnt moved in hours?

Comment: There's a missing puzzle piece here. You say your bill was 3X normal, which is based on movement of the meter. If the meter isn't moving then the bill does not go up. Something has changed (besides the water main). Did you change any fixtures or appliances? What about irrigation/lawn sprinklers?

Comment: Changing the line size will not affect your ussage is it possible your meter reading was estimated and when a real reading was done some of the data from when there was a leak was included. Years ago when I lived in the city I had a main line failure. We shut off the water and fed from our neighbors house fixed all our problems and several months later received a huge bill the city said it only really checked 1 time per quarter could this be the same issue?

Comment: Thanks Ed, Im also thinking new size line has nothing to do with it. I think I understand you and are saying we had an inaccurate meter reading a moth before and got hit with two months worth of a leak all at once. Nothing has changed at all. My current reading is for 11 days and is around 2 units. Before we fixed the leak our monthly usage was 2-3 units. So for the remainder of the month we are looking at 5-6 units and we arent using any more water then normal.

Comment: The month before I fixed the leak we were normal usage. The leak was repaired on the 4th day of a very small leak. I dont think could possibly account for 500 gallons of water and I doubt I discovered the leak on the day it started since the leak itself was in the pipe inside the meter box. The meter had been submerged in water and mud for I dont know how long. But unless I found the leak on the day it started the bill from the previous month should have also been higher unless the guy reading it the month before didnt do it right.

Comment: Timing is everything. Are you quite sure about the timing of the leak vs. the timing of the meter readings and billing statements?  There can be quite a lag in there. You could easily fix a leak on July 5 and pay for the leak in August.  Also re-read Ed Beal's comment about estimated usage.  He is saying the readings were correct *when actually made*, but they skip readings because sending a man out there is expensive.  They extrapolate from previous readings, and if that captured the leak period, it's the gift that keeps on giving!  It will balance in the end.

Comment: And yes, a leak can be *that much*.  What you forget is when you watch them, it's a tiny amount of water. But it leaks 24x7 constantly, it never sleeps. That's how your cable box can take more energy than your dryer.